# Non context-free languages closed under reverse

Tags: examples-counterexamples, context-free-grammar

Is this sentence true or false? I'll be glad for some explaination

L is not context-free, then its reverse is also not context-free

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reverse of context-free is also context-free, moreover reverse$^2$ is identity, so $rev(L) \in CFL$ would imply $L = rev(rev(L)) \in CFL$.

Comment: OK I got it, thanks :)